# ¿ Es posible tener un profiler de consultas en mysql similar al SQL PROFILER?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una aplicación en php, y cuando realizo acciones o reportes quisiera darle el seguimiento de que querys se están ejecutando, he probado con JET PROFILER y otras aplicaciones que mencionan darle seguimiento pero cuando ejecuto la aplicación PHP no muestra ningun resultado, he probado la consola de mysql pero para transacciones recurrentes como que el seguimiento resulta engorroso. Tendrán alguna sugerencia?

Comment: En MySQL existe algo similar desde la version 5.0.37. Ver [esto](http://web.archive.org/web/20110609054749/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html) y también el [Manual de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html)

Comment: En efecto, pude revisar esas instrucciones pero sólo identifica consultas a nivel de consola, las aplicaciones que ejecuto por el servidor no registra ningún movimiento.